# Syntax Error with lists in Python

Tags: python, list

python version: 2.71

I get a syntax error whenever I try to run it with IDLE....

```
horsemen = ["war", "famine", "pestilence", "death"]
i = 0
while i < 4:
    print horsemen[i]
    i = i + 1
```

The error occurs between horsemen and the equal sign

Comment: Please format your source code properly and provide a full description was "syntax error" means in form of the full traceback!

Comment: And where is the exact traceback showing the error? Please no verbal blabla like occurs between.....

Comment: it looks like identation is only 2 spaces long

Comment: i closed the IDLE and opened it again. Now it works fine. I have no idea what went wrong...

Comment: As Jakob points out, this is not the way to write loops in Python, anyway.

Comment: uhhh..i coped the code from a web page.

http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy/html/chap08.html

Comment: A better book to learn from is learn python the hard way

Comment: thanks. yeah sorry guys this was a bad question. i should have captured a screen shot of the error message.

Comment: @Charlie: "Screen shot"?  You mean "copy and paste".  The error messages are text.  Please copy and paste the text.  Also, please update the question to indicate which version of Python you're using.

Comment: @Charlie The [web page](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy/html/chap08.html) you refer to goes on to improve the code in section 8.5: "_The for loop is more concise because we can eliminate the loop variable, i. Here is the previous loop written with a for loop._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine (syntactically). You must have a problem with your python environment. Also make sure it is properly indented.

Comment: what do you mean by python environment?

Comment: Actually before you do anything, make sure you don't have an indention error. Post the error you are getting. By that I mean copy and paste the exact syntax error you are getting.

Comment: it's just a pop up box that says syntax error, and on the source code the space between horsemen and the equal sign was highlighted.

Comment: I closed the IDLE and opened it again. Now it works fine and doesn't show any error. weird...

Comment: That is strange, it sounds like a bug. I have seen problems like that in other python IDE's. To be honest, I don't use an IDE for python, you lose a lot of the advantages of a IDE when using an interpreted dynamically typed language.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer YAY for me! Seriously though, the question was "Whats wrong with it?" not "How can I do this better?" Although, they are pretty much the same question but you know what I mean :)

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer sorry, i just couldn't comprehend your for loop at first sight.

Answer (score 8):

Is there any reason you cannot use a for loop?

```
for god in horsemen:
    print god
```

Comment: well in edgecases I might forgo the for loop for a while loop. Like reading a large file.

Comment: so basically in a for loop one can put anything after "for"?

to me it'll seem more confusing....

Comment: @Charlie - not 'anything'. Put there a variable name that describes one element of the list the best.

Comment: @GufyMike Id rather use a for loop over while any day of the week. There are few cases for is not better than while.

Comment: Since [the four horsemen of the apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Horsemen_of_the_Apocalypse) is a biblical concept, wherein there is, you know, only one god, labeling the horsemen as gods is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Thats a philosophical question rather than a programming (python) problem I could have called it `foo in horsemen` personally I don't believe in god but that shouldn't infringe on our work here.

Comment: @Jakob Of course you're right it doesn't matter for the programming. I'm just nitpicking, since I enjoy doing that so much, and my nerdiness does not limit itself to programming topics.

Comment: I can agree with that sometimes it is just fun to 'troll'

Comment: @Tim, thinking binary data and reading out bytes into a buffer. for line in file: doesn't fit that bill in my mind. Call it a lack of understanding the deep semantics of that specific use of the for loop, the while loop has always served well, when reading large files.